# Write a query to add a flag to each user if they've added a new employer in the current year

Tags: sql

```
    employers table

    column  type
    user_id integer
    year    string 
    employer_ein    string
```

We're given a table called employers that consists of a user_id, year, and employer EIN label. Users can have multiple employers dictated by the different EIN labels.
Write a query to add a flag to each user if they've added a new employer in the current year.

```
   Example: 

   employer

   user_id    year    employer_ein
   # 34323      2018    A 
   # 34323      2018    B
   # 34323      2018    C
   # 34323      2017    F
   # 34323      2017    A
   # 34323      2017    B

   # 86323      2018    A
   # 86323      2018    B
   # 86323      2018    C
   # 86323      2017    B
   # 
   # 98787      2018    A
   # 98787      2018    B
   # 98787      2018    F
   # 98787      2017    F
   # 98787      2017    B
   # 98787      2017    A
   # 
   # 55559      2018    A
   # 55559      2018    B
   # 55559      2018    C


   # Output
   # user_id    year    new_ein_flag
   # 34323      2018      1
   # 86323      2018      1
   # 98787      2018      0
```

Comment: Show us what you did and tried. Tell us what didn't work and what exactly you need the community's help for.

Comment: Sure, I'll do that soon. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions and aggregation:

```
select user_id, year,
       max(case when min_year = year then 1 else 0 end) as new_ein_flag
from (select t.*,
             min(year) over (partition by user_id, ein) as min_year
      from t
     ) t
where year = 2018
group by user_id, year;
```

The inner query calculates the minimum year per `user_id`/`ein` pair.  The outer query only keeps rows from the current year and calculates the flag if any `ein`s have their minimum as the current year.

EDIT:

If you have to figure out the most recent year, just use window functions again:

```
select user_id, year,
       max(case when min_year = year then 1 else 0 end) as new_ein_flag
from (select t.*, max(year) over () as max_year,
             min(year) over (partition by user_id, ein) as min_year
      from t
     ) t
where year = max_year
group by user_id, year;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Hello, What if there were more years 2016,2015 etc ? Sorry I didn't follow it, how will 2018 be equal to min year ? Can you please explain in more detail

Comment: @user13972665 . . . Technically, the current year would be `extract(year from current_date)`.  However, in your example it obviously seemed to be 2018.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the solution,really helped me understand a different perspective!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    select user_id,max(year) as year, max(sumrow) as maxsumrow,
(case min(sumrow) = 1 and max(sumrow) = 2 when TRUE then 1 when FALSE then 0 end) as new_ein_flag 
from 
(SELECT user_id,count(*) as sumrow, max(year) as year,employer_ein FROM `ein` GROUP BY user_id,employer_ein) as grouptable
where year = (select max(year) as maxyear from ein)
group by user_id
 having max(sumrow)=2
```

I tried it. it is screenshot;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you're tired from the analytical functions

```
WITH 
max_date_for_cross_join AS (
 SELECT MAX(dt) AS m_dt FROM employer ), 
stg AS (
SELECT user_id                                                                     AS user_id
     , MAX(s.m_dt)                                                                 AS year
     , CASE WHEN MIN(e.dt)=MAX(e.dt) AND MAX(e.dt) = MAX(s.m_dt) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS new_ein_flag
     , MIN(e.dt)                                                                   AS min_dt
  FROM employer                      e
       CROSS JOIN 
       max_date_for_cross_join       s
GROUP BY user_id
       , employer_ein)
SELECT user_id             AS user_id
     , MAX(year)           AS year
     , MAX(new_ein_flag)   AS new_ein_flag
  FROM stg
 GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN min_dt < year THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Usually a code block with no explanation is not a very good answer. It helps the community much more if you could tell us why we should try this code and why it would/might help the op. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With res AS(

select  A.User_id, A.year, count(A.employer_ein) as cnt

from Users A left join Users B on A.User_id=B.User_id and A.year=B.year+1
and A.employer_ein=B.employer_ein

where
B.user_id is  null and A.year=2018
GROUP by A.User_id,A.year
)

select distinct case when R.user_id is null then U.user_id when R.user_id is not null then R.user_id end as userid,

case when R.year is null then U.year when R.year is not null then R.year end as year,

case when R.cnt is null then 0 when cnt>0 then 1 end as new_ein_flag from res R right join Users U on R.user_id=U.user_id

where U.year=2018

Comment: Please review and apply coding standards when sharing code with others. Might I reccommend this link:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/04/sql-server-database-coding-standards-and-guidelines-part-1/